# Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 guildMemberAdd listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a welcome message but it makes my bot spam the welcome message for some reason can someone help?

Here is my code:

```
    // Send the message to a designated channel on a server:
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'yo');


    // Do nothing if the channel wasn't found on this server
    if (!channel) return;

    const welcome = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`***Welcome to Tracy*** ${member}***Boost Us!***`)
    .setImage('https://media0.giphy.com/media/SwUpQs8oVWvZG5vpyS/giphy.gif')
    .setColor(0x5933A0)
    message.channel.send(welcome);
  });
```

This is the error it gives me:

"Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 guildMemberAdd listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit"

**Where do I put the emitter.setMaxListeners() and what else should be included?**

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's hard to debug the problem with the code you provided.

Comment: Well the error is clear, you are setting 11 client.on("guildMemberAdd"); now you just gotta figure out how, check any code relevant to that file like a command handler or the main js

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so obviously this isn't normal.

What is your node version? Do you have multiple guildMemberAdd events?

This can help debug: [NodeJS setMaxListeners](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n)

You can try putting this in your code: `process.on('warning', e => console.warn(e.stack));`

Comment: Yes. Also, this can be caused by a lot of guildMemberAdd events, check how many you have.